# take a line from a file and change it by what is the beginning of the line

Tags: python, file, if-statement, statements, readlines

So I want to look in the file something and when I read a line that begins with # I want to print something in the front of the line and in the end of it.

```
file = open("something.py","r")
infile = file.readlines()

for line in infile:
    if line.find("#") !=-1:
        index = line.find("#")
        print("BLABLABLA",the line that begins with #,"BLABLABLA", end="")
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: You should start with [`.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

Comment: do you have to do it in same file or can write in new one?

Comment: Am I supposed to put index in the place of  "the line that begins with# #"??

Comment: I want the entire line that begins with # to be between my two BLABLABLA not just #.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
# Open file for reading
with open("infile.txt", "r") as infile:
    # Open another file for writing
    with open("outfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
        # Read each line from the input file
        for line in infile.readlines():
            # Check if line begins with keyword "Hello"
            if line.startswith("Hello"):
                # If it does, prepend and append something to the line
                line = "Prepend! >>> " + line.strip() + " <<< Append!"
            # Finally, write the line to outfile
            outfile.write(line + "\n")
```

Input:

```
Hello, this is a line.
Hello, this is another line.
Goodbye, these were all the lines
```

Output:

```
Prepend! >>> Hello, this is a line. <<< Append!
Prepend! >>> Hello, this is another line. <<< Append!
Goodbye, these were all the lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple & short. The last two lines will change depending on your flag and what you want to actually do with the line read.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            print('!!!' + line.strip() + '!!!')
```